# Android alarm custom ringtone

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to set a custom ringtone from my sdcard music folder with alarm.
   I have displayed all songs from my sdcard in a listview but on     onItemClickListner how i can set selected song as a ringtone of scheduled alarm.

Comment: try to use ringtonepreference in settings activity. It is easy

Comment: sir, firstly i got all songs from my music directory to in a ListView, after selecting a song from list a set it as a rigtone using Contentvalues and URI of song and on other button i am setting alarm but on particulr scheduled alarm time no alarm sound listen.

Comment: Please share your code of creating alarm